# How to .htaccess pseudo-static + hidden extension?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Why can't I use the following?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

`.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Can you explain what you try to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to use both
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
> RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
> ```

The first rule rewrites *everything* to `index.php`. The directives that follow are effectively ignored.

However, the second rule also rewrites *everything* (same pattern `^(.*)$` - obvious conflict), that doesn't map to an existing file or directory to append a `.html` extension. This second rule is more restrictive.

It seems that what you want to do is:

1. Append the `.html` extension to URLs that would map to `.html` files.
2. Rewrite all other requests that (I assume) do not map to physical files and directories to `index.php`.

Additional assumptions

- The `.htaccess` file is located in the document root.
- Requested URLs that should map to `.html` files do not contain dots in the URL-path. Therefore, dots in the URL-path indicate file extensions only.
- If you literally rewrite *everything* else to `index.php` (as you were doing) then it will also rewrite all your static resources (CSS, JS, images, etc.), so I assume you want to make exceptions for static resources and anything that would otherwise map to a file or directory.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Append the ".html" extension if the target file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^.])$ $1.html [L]

# Rewrite other requests that don't map to files/directories to index.php
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(?:css|js|jpg|png|gif)$ index.php [L]
```